# Do I have to run rake db:test:load each time manually before runnings tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.
I'm trying to set up a simple WebApp via Scaffolding. And using RSpec for my tests. Now after the scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold VideoSegment file_path:string short_name:string description:string
```

I ran `rake db:migrate`, but thats clear, bringing the data to my development database.
But the tests where not green before I did:

```
rake db:test:load
```

To bring the schema of my development database to the test database. Isn't there a way to automate this step? Or do I have to load test database again after each scaffold?

PS: Of course I know Scaffold is not doing the finest things, but for my proof of concept need it's sufficient.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The rake db:test:load is done once. You won't have to repeat it.

Comment: Even not after another scaffold acion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you run rspec it will prepare the test schema for you using the task: `db:test:prepare`

So after generating migrations you have to do rake db:migrate to update the development schema and then run you spec which will automatically prepare the test database for you.

Comment: But why I had to do both, `db:migrate` and `db:test:load` to get the tests passing?